# How to append double quotes to password file

Tags: shell-script, sed, scripting

How can i append double quote to passwd file with sed or other utilities:

Source File:

```
user1:x:1:1:User1:/home/user1:/bin/bash
user2:x:2:2:User2:/home/user2:/bin/bash
user3:x:3:3:User3:/home/user3:/bin/bash
```

What i am looking to do:

```
"user1":"x":"1":"1":"User1":"/home/user1":"/bin/bash"
"user2":"x":"2":"2":"User2":"/home/user2":"/bin/bash"
"user3":"x":"3":"3":"User3":"/home/user3":"/bin/bash"
```

Comment: This smells like an XY problem: why do you want to do this?

Comment: with sed, you would globally search and replace `:` with `":"`, and you would replace the start of line, and the end of line, with `"`

Comment: ... or globally search and replace *non*-`:` sequences `[^:]*` with `"&"`?

Comment: hopefully none of the users has a single `"` in their GECOS

Comment: @glennjackman an audit team want the file with quote, i think for integrating the line on their tools

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
sed 's/[^:]*/"&"/g' /etc/passwd
```

That is enclose in quote any sequence of 0 or more (`*`) characters other than `:` (`[^:]`).

Or using a dedicated csv-processing tool which would have the benefit of properly quoting (csv-style) fields that contain double quote characters, and here also adding a header:

```
mlr --icsvlite --ocsv --implicit-csv-header --fs : --quote-all label \
  'User Name,Password,UID,GID,Gecos,Home Directory,Shell' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: Just Perfect for my case tanks @Stéphane

Answer (score 2):

I have done by below method

command:

```
sed 's/:/"&"/g' filename | sed 's/^/"/'| sed 's/$/"/'
```

or,

```
sed 's/:/"&"/g; s/^/"/; s/$/"/' filename
```

output:

```
"user1":"x":"1":"1":"User1":"/home/user1":"/bin/bash"
"user2":"x":"2":"2":"User2":"/home/user2":"/bin/bash"
"user3":"x":"3":"3":"User3":"/home/user3":"/bin/bash"
```

Comment: and since the replacement text is static, it's less computation (for the computer and the human reading it) to just say `sed 's/:/":"/g'`, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk` (not as short as the `sed` solution though):

```
$ awk -F ':' -v OFS='":"' '{ $1 = "\"" $1; $NF = $NF "\""; print }' file
"user1":"x":"1":"1":"User1":"/home/user1":"/bin/bash"
"user2":"x":"2":"2":"User2":"/home/user2":"/bin/bash"
"user3":"x":"3":"3":"User3":"/home/user3":"/bin/bash"
```

This sets the output field delimiter (`OFS`) to the string `":"` and then prepends `"` to the first `:`-delimited field and append the same to the last field.  It then prints the resulting record.

---

`awk` again, but iterating over the fields, adding double quotes to each before outputting the modified record:

```
awk -F ':' -v OFS=':' '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) $i=sprintf("\"%s\"", $i); print }' file
```

---

Reading the file as if it was a `:`-delimited CSV file using `csvformat` from [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.3/):

```
$ csvformat -d ':' -D ':' -U 1 file
"user1":"x":"1":"1":"User1":"/home/user1":"/bin/bash"
"user2":"x":"2":"2":"User2":"/home/user2":"/bin/bash"
"user3":"x":"3":"3":"User3":"/home/user3":"/bin/bash"
```

Here, we tell `csvformat` that both the input and the output field delimiter should be `:` and that we want quoting of all fields regardless of whether it's actually needed or not.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, Ruby:

```
ruby -rcsv -e '
    csv_in  = CSV.new File.new ARGV.shift, col_sep: ":"
    csv_out = CSV.new $stdout,             col_sep: ":", force_quotes: true
    csv_in.each {|row| csv_out << row}
' /etc/passwd
```